# Justifying that $S=\left\{f \in X: \int f(t)dt=0\right\}$ is compact and connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

> Consider the space $X=C[0,1]$ with its usual sup-norm topology. Let
>
> $$S=\left\{f \in X: \int f(t)dt=0\right\}.$$
>
> Justify:
>
> - S is compact.
> - S is connected.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this question, explaining what's giving you difficulty.

Comment: The members of S are bounded, but S itself is not. Given N, can you find a function $f\in S$ with $\Vert f\Vert>N$? Yes you can. As an unbounded set in a metric space, $S$ cannot be compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\;f,g\in S\;$ , so for all $\;t\in[0,1]\;$ :

$$\int\limits_0^1(tf(x)+(1-t)g(x))dx=t\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx+(1-t)\int\limits_0^1g(x)dx=0+0=0\implies$$

$$tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)\in S\implies S\;\text{is path connected and thus connected}$$

Now define

$$\forall\,N\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;\;f_N(x)=2Nx-N$$

It's easy to check $\;f_N\in S\;$ and $\;||f_N||_\infty=N\;$ so $\;S\;$ isn't bounded...

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $S$ is a vector subspace of $C[0,1]$, hence it's pathwise connected.

$S$ is not compact because it's not bounded; actually, $S\cap \overline{B(0,1)}$ is not compact. Consider indeed the sequence $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ given by $f_n(x):=\sin(2n\pi x)$. Then $f_n\in S\cap \overline{B(0,1)}$ for each $n$, but the family is not equi-continuous.

Comment: Is it always true that a vector subspace is connected?  Why?